# How does one use EPS as a valuable tool in evaluating an equity?

Tags: investing, equity, corporate-earnings, earnings-per-share, metric

EPS (Earnings Per Share) is typically listed along with what seems to be much more insightful metrics for equities.

Is EPS useful in it's own right, or does one need to plug it in to an equation to make it useful?

Let's create a simplified example to examine this:

Let's first look at fictional company ABC.  Their total earnings are €100 per annum.  100% of their company is divided into 5 shares.  Thus, the EPS will be €20.

Now, let's compare that to fictional company XYZ.  Their total earnings are €100 per annum.  100% of their company is divided into 10 shares.  Thus, their EPS will be €10.

The EPS of ABC is 2x that of XYZ, but the earnings of both companies are identical.  Thus, it seems like EPS, unless plugged into a formula, is almost meaningless.  By itself, the only real value seems to be if it is positive or negative.

How does one use EPS as a valuable tool in evaluating an equity?

Comment: EPS isn’t good enough on its own in evaluations (as D Stanley said). What I think all evaluations come down to is: “how much money is this company going to continue making, and how will that affect the price of what I own?”. One word of advice in evaluations is to pretend like you’re going to buy the whole company.

Answer (score 1):

The EPS number is valuable as it tells you the earnings you get per share as a shareholder. If you owned the whole company then it would not matter but since a shareholder owns a fraction of the company it matters how much (hypothetically) you own from the earnings.

In your example, it is true that both companies earn $100 in total, but if you own 1 share of ABC you as a shareholder own 20% of the earnings of ABC and therefore if all the earnings were to be distributed you will get $20. If you had owned 1 share of XYZ you will own only 10% of the earnings and therefore have a claim to $10 of the earnings.

So in the case of the XYZ company, you will have to own twice as many shares to get the claim to the same amount as ABC. Now if the price of both company’s shares is identical, it is obvious that buying 1 share of ABC is a much better value than buying 1 share of XYZ.

It makes it more intuitive if you imagine that all the earnings are distributed at the end of the year as a dividend to shareholders. Therefore EPS become DPS (Dividend per share) and you as a shareholder get DPS multiplied by the number of shares you own of the company.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that EPS by itself is not useful - but just "plugging it into a formula" does not always help either. There is a lot of context behind an individual company's earnings that need to be considered as well.

The most common use of EPS is to compare it to the stock price ("P/E Ratio"). That tells you how much you're paying for those earnings (or, how "cheap" a stock is compared to its earning potential). But even that is not always enough to completely evaluate a company.

How consistent are the earnings? How much are they growing? Are there irregular ("non-recurring") expenses or revenues that are skewing the earnings? Are there "creative accounting" measures taking place that may skew the earnings? How do the earnings compare to other similar companies?

All of those are additional questions that should be evaluated as well. Not all of them are completely quantifiable, either.

Comment: Thanks.  Since P/E is literally price over earnings, doesn't that already tell you how much shareholders paying for those earnings?  What does knowing the EPS add?

Comment: Not much by itself, but it can be used to calculate other ratios (ROE, etc.) or it can be looked at  _over time_ to see if the company is growing.

Comment: Thanks again.  To look at it over time (and have meaning), one would also have to know if the company issued more shares, right?

Comment: True, which is not common, but yes that should be taken into context (although if a company issues more shares you'd expect them to use the money to continue to grow the company).

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, P/E is literally price over earnings *per share.*  You need to know EPS to get to P/E.

Comment: @quid Right. Many sites providing obviously useful values such as P/E and yield.  They also often list EPS visually the same way (often in the same box).  This could just be bad design, but it implies equal importance for EPS.  What I'm wondering is if EPS, by itself, is meaningful.

Comment: It's as useful as share price.  Almost no data point is useful by itself.